# C# Hastable of Objetcs

Tags: c#, list, class, hashtable

I have objects in hashtable, in that object I have a list, how to access it?

```
ls.cs


         class lh 
                {
                    public string name;
                    public  List<ulong> nList = new List<ulong>(); 

                    public lh(string name)
                    {
                        this.name = name; ;
                    }
                }

    Program.cs

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    while((line=ps.ReadLine()) != null) 
    { 
        gen.h_lh.Add(line, new lh(line));
    }
    }    
    public class gen
        {
          public static Hashtable h_lh = new Hashtable();
        }
```

this works. when I debug I can see the object created in the hashtable; I just cant/dont know how to access/store value to the list
it's gotta be something like gen.h_lh[lh].something right ? but this didnt work. what did I miss?

Comment: See documentation and example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Comment: Are you sure HashTable is the appropriate data structure? If you're planning to iterate over every entry, maybe you want a List<Tuple<string, lh>>

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Hashtable` is obsolete, use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead (`Dictionary<string, lh>` in your case).

Given a key, you can access the value of that key with: `h_lh[key]`.

Or you can enumerate all of the key/value pairs with:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, lh> pair in h_lh)
    pair.Value // this is an lh object
```

You can also enumerate just keys `h_lh.Keys`, or just values `h_lh.Values`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(System.System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in h_lh) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + entry.Key.ToString() + " | " + "Value: " + entry.Value.ToString());  
}
```

or you could access it using a key

```
lh myLh = h_lh[line];
```

Update answer for comment

```
foreach(System.System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in h_lh) 
{
    List<ulong> nList = (ulong)entry.Value; 
    nList.Add(1); 
}
```

Comment: the object is already created. the Hashtable gen.h_lh has multiple objects created. I just need to give value to the object's nList

Answer (score 0):

A hash tables is a data structure that represents a set. That means that by definition, you don't want to access the hash table to get an element, you just want to add, remove, or aks if an element exists. These are the basic operations with sets.

This said, `HashSet<T>` in .NET has no indexer. Why? Consider the line that you wrote yourself:

```
var item = gen.h_lh[lh]
```

If you really can provide the `lh` to index, what do you expect the hash table to give you? The same instance? Of course not, you already have it, if you are using it in the indexer. So perhaps your problem it's not very well determined.

First of all you need to determine why (and how) you want to access the elements. All you want  is to iterate through all of them, or you want to quickly index any one of them? If you just want to get all the elements at some point, then you have all you need: `HashSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. If you need to get an specific element, then you must have some *key* to identify the element (like the `name` property here), and in this case what you want is not a `HashSet<lh>` but a `Dictionary<string,lh>`, just like @Tergiver said.

Comment: Actually, by looking at the structure of your `lh` class, perhaps all you need is a `Dictionary<string,List<ulong>>`, since it seems no useful to me to store those strings in the values, if their purpose is just to be keys.

Comment: Given that `HashSet<T>` does not have to use the base (non-overridden) `Object.GetHashCode` and `Object.Equals` methods, there are many situations where, it is entirely possible to have an object which matches one in the hash table according to the supplied hashing/comparison methods, but is nonetheless semantically different.  As a simple example, suppose one wants to read as `String` a million lines of text from a file that is expected to contain many duplicates.  `String.Intern` would keep strings in memory forever; one could use a `Dictionary<String, String>` but that would seem silly.

Comment: What would seem ideal would be to build a `HashSet<T>` as one read the file; any time a line was read that was already in that `HashSet<T>`, one could ditch the newly-read string in favor of the existing one.  Once the whole file was read, one could ditch the `HashSet`.

Comment: I once had this problem, with a hashset of LrItem for a compiler. I used the kernel to hash, and had a list of items in the follow. So many LrItems had the same kernel but different follows, and I had to mix them. The solution was to move to a `Dictionary<LrKernel, LrFollow>`.